# Java MapReduce - How to Output Top 10 from an IntWritable Sum in Reducer Class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm having difficulty writing my reducer code for a Top 10 (key,value) pair output.

My current output is formatted as ((Year, Market), Total Amount). What I'm looking for are the Top 10 Total Amounts for each Year. My current code is outputting every amount for every market for each year.

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated!

Mapper:

```
public class FundingMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

private Text Year = new Text();
private Text Market = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));

    String[] array = reader.readNext();
    reader.close();

    Year.set(array[14]);
    Market.set(array[3]);

    String amountString = array[15].replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
    int amount = 0;

    try {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(amountString);
    }

    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return;
    }

    IntWritable intW = new IntWritable(amount);

    String S = new StringBuilder().append(Year + " ").append(Market + " ").toString();

    context.write(new Text(S), intW);
}
}
```

Reducer:

```
public class FundingReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, 
        InterruptedException {

    int sum = 0;

    for(IntWritable value : values) {
        sum += value.get();
    }

    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
}
```

Data sample:

```
/organization/contravir-pharmaceuticals ContraVir Pharmaceuticals   |Biotechnology| Biotechnology   USA NY  New York City   New York    /funding-round/9a7cc724deba554585e2b79c14605866 post_ipo_equity     8/22/14 2014-08      2014-Q3    2014    4,742,648

/organization/contravir-pharmaceuticals ContraVir Pharmaceuticals   |Biotechnology| Biotechnology   USA NY  New York City   New York    /funding-round/04a7ec54417a0f9a6c99cf8db2eac819 venture A   10/15/14    2014-10  2014-Q4    2014    9,000,000    

/organization/contravir-pharmaceuticals ContraVir Pharmaceuticals   |Biotechnology| Biotechnology   USA NY  New York City   New York    /funding-round/328384053df3a992ca6d5da55ca0420e venture     2/14/14 2014-02  2014-Q1    2014    3,225,000    

/organization/contrib-com   contrib.com |Entrepreneur|Technology|Domains|Education|Social Media|    Social Media    USA FL  Palm Beaches    Delray Beach    /funding-round/fea112ed22657c1456820aa26af3ab17 seed        6/17/14 2014-06  2014-Q2    2014    300,000
```

Output sample:

```
2014  Biotechnology  16967648
2014  Social Media  300000
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have key as Year in your map output. This will ensure that you will get values for each year at a time in reducer. And later you can filter out just 10 values to your output. Just check below.

```
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));

        String[] array = reader.readNext();
        reader.close();

        Year.set(array[14]);
        Market.set(array[3]);

        String amountString = array[15].replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
        int amount = 0;

        try {
            amount = Integer.parseInt(amountString);
        }

        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return;
        }

        IntWritable intW = new IntWritable(amount);

        context.write(new Intwritable(Year), new Text(amount +" "+ market));
    }

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, 
            InterruptedException {

        int count= 0;
        int amount =0;
        string market = "";
        for(IntWritable value : values) {
           market = value.toString().split(" ")[1];
           amount = Integer.parseInt(value.toString.split(" ")[0])
            if(count < 10){
              count ++;
              context.write(key, value);
          }
else
 break;
        }

       // context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
```

Comment: I should have clarified this in my initial post, so I apologize for that, but I need the **sum** formula within the _for loop_ because there are multiple entries in my data with the same Year and Market. I need to get the Total Amount sum prior to outputting the Top 10. I also need my output to have the Year, Market, and Total Amount, so I need the concatenation that I have in there as well.

Comment: I think its a bit complex. Can you please provide an example data set and sample output so that we can discuss more on implementation.

Comment: I added a small sample to my original post. Let me know if you'd like a larger sample size.

Comment: Again, this is my fault for not explaining this thoroughly. I'm sorry. I'm looking for the 10 **greatest** Total Amounts for each year along with the corresponding market. I appreciate your help thus far.